# Results are repeating in DB::getInstance

Tags: php, sql-server

I am new to php and I am trying to develop a class. I am connected to sqlsrv and  the connection is fine. Its when I run the query the results are repeating almost like it's in a loop. I can not find the problem and I was hoping an extra pair of eyes can help. Any help is appreciated!

```
class DB{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_connection, 
            $_query, 
            $_error = false, 
            $_results, 
            $_count = 0;

private function __construct(){
    $mssqlInfo = array( "Database"=>"db");  
    $mssqlServer = "server";
    $this->_connection = sqlsrv_connect($mssqlServer, $mssqlInfo); 
    if($this->_connection === false ) {  
     echo '<h2>Unable to connect to database</h2><br/>'; 
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
    }else{
        //echo 'Connected';
    }
}

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()){ 
        $this->_error = false;
        $options = array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC );
        $this->_query = sqlsrv_query($this->_connection, $sql, $params,$options);
        if($this->_query){
            $this->_results = sqlsrv_fetch_object($this->_query);
            $this->_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($this->_query);
        }else{
            $this->_error = true;
            echo 'Error in statement execution.\n'; 
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

        }           
        return $this;          
    } 
public function action($action, $table, $where = array()){
    if(count($where) === 3){
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} (?)";

            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public function get($table, $where){
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}
public function delete($table, $where){
    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
}

public function results(){
    return $this->_results;
}

public function first(){
    return $this->results()[0];
}

public function error(){
    return $this->_error;
}

public function count(){
    return $this->_count;
}


 }
```

here is the instance on the index page that I am using to test my functions and to retrieve the query.

```
    require_once 'core/init.php';

    $users = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    $user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'mike'));

 if(!$user->count()){
    echo 'No user';
}else{
    $obj = $users->results();
    foreach($obj as $users){
        echo $users->username;
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

I forgot to included the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [username] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [password] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [salt] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [joined] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [group] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fetch only one row of the results in function query() and save it to member _results:
$this->_results = sqlsrv_fetch_object($this->_query);

Then you use function results() in a while loop. results() returns an object saved in member _results which will never change. That's why you got an endless loop.

Solution for your problem:
Change

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){ 
        [...]
        $this->_query = sqlsrv_query($this->_connection, $sql, $params,$options);
        if($this->_query){
            $this->_results = sqlsrv_fetch_object($this->_query);
            $this->_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($this->_query);
        [...]
```

to

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){ 
        [...]
        $this->_query = $sql;
        $this->_results = sqlsrv_query($this->_connection, $sql, $params,$options);
        if($this->_query){
            $this->_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($this->_query);
        [...]
```

And change

```
public function results(){
    return $this->_results;
}
```

to

```
public function results(){
    return sqlsrv_fetch_object($this->_results);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Izzet, I found that out but say i want to query all users is the fetch_object. when I run a foreach loop I receive an error. Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: There is an easy solution for your problem. I will edit my answer to show you what to change

Comment: I made the changes but I'm still getting the error, but now I did a var_dump($user); and I am able to see the _query string. Before I wasn't able to but thats because we stored it as a string... nevermind

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting $obj to $user->results() in your while loop, so it's always true and therefore never stops.

Just change it to a foreach().

```
$obj = $user->results();

foreach ($obj as $user) {
    echo $user->username;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Daniel, Thank you for the quick response. I made the changes you recommended  but now I am receiving an error message. I forgot to include my database table structure.

Comment: Daniel here is the error message I received:PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in phplogin\index.php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in \phplogin\index.php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in phplogin\index.php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in phplogin\index.php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in phplogin\index.php on line 15

Comment: do var_dump($user). What do you get?

Comment: 2 (5) { ["_connection":"DB":private]=> resource(5) of type (SQL Server Connection) ["_query":"DB":private]=> resource(6) of type (SQL Server Statement) ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) ["_results":"DB":private]=> object(stdClass)#4 (7) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["username"]=> string(4) "mike" ["password"]=> string(8) "password" ["salt"]=> string(4) "salt" ["name"]=> string(4) "Mike" ["joined"]=> object(DateTime)#3 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-11-17 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(15) "America/Chicago" } ["group"]=> int(1) } ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(1) }

Comment: Okay, so $user->results() is not actually getting the results. Try $user['_results']->username or $user['_results']['username']

Comment: Daniel I really apperate you helping me in this situation, I did both and I got the same error. PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DB as array